# Java 8 Date/Time API equivalent of 'new Date().toString()'

Tags: java, date, java-time

Is there an equivalent to `new Date().toString()` (`Date` from `java.util.Date`) in Java 8's new Date-Time API?

If I do the following:

```
System.out.println(new Date());
```

this gives me by default a nice readable result like this:

> Sat Jan 03 12:58:46 CET 2015

(depends a little bit on the locale)

In Java 8 (the new ways, I know that the above way is still working) I see the following ways to get a date string "directly" (without additional formatting):

```
System.out.println(Clock.systemUTC().instant());
```

results in something like:

> 2015-01-03T12:03:58.614Z

This is not really readable and requires some additional formatting.

Another way:

```
System.out.println(LocalDateTime.now());
```

results in:

> 2015-01-03T13:00:58.594

This is nearly the same as the last one, but without the timezone Z at the end.

Because the desired date string should also contain the timezone, I tried the following:

```
System.out.println(ZonedDateTime.now());
```

This prints:

> 2015-01-03T13:00:35.277+01:00[Europe/Berlin]

which is also unusable.

I know that I can easily format the date by passing an instance of `DateTimeFormatter` to the `format()` method of `ZonedDateTime` or by using one of the existing ones like this:

```
System.out.println(ZonedDateTime.now().format(DateTimeFormatter.RFC_1123_DATE_TIME));
```

prints out:

> Sat, 3 Jan 2015 13:01:25 +0100

which would be acceptable for me as result. But it requires additional formatting, which is what I want to avoid.

So, is there a way to get something similar if not equivalent to `new Date().toString()` with the new Java 8 Date-Time classes?

Comment: If `Date.toString()` is what you want, why not use it?

Comment: Because this requires to have a `Date` object and I want to use the new API for working with dates...

Comment: Then you'll have to use formatting. I don't know why you'd want to avoid it anyways. It's the only safe way to make sure you get the dates you want.

Comment: Why you don't use [DateFormat](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/text/DateFormat.html)?

Comment: "*This is not really readable*" - is a matter of taste. In fact I find the ISO formatting easier to read.

Comment: Those "unreadable" formats are defined by the [ISO 8601](http://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/ISO_8601) standard. They actually are quite readable in a few ways: they are unambiguously precise, they are intuitively decipherable in nearly any culture, and they sort alphabetically as chronological.. While not meant for common presentation to most users, those formats are extremely useful to programmers during debugging, system administrators in logs, accountants in audit trails, other systems exchanging serialized data, and other such scenarios.

Answer (score 2):

You need to use a formatter to replicate the format of `java.util.Date`. Declare the formatter using a pattern:

```
private static final DateTimeFormatter FORMATTER =
    DateTimeFormatter.ofPattern("EEE MMM dd HH:mm:ss zzz yyyy");
```

(using a `static` constant is recommended)

Then use a `ZonedDateTime` and format it using *one* of these methods:

```
ZonedDateTime zdt = ZonedDateTime.now();
System.out.println(zdt.format(FORMATTER));
System.out.println(FORMATTER.format(zdt));
```

See also `DateTimeFormatter.ofLocalizedDateTime(FormatStyle.LONG)` for more localized formats.